# How to disable snap filesystem sandboxing

Tags: software-installation, snap

I've lost count of how many times gimp/krita/lmms/other software that would work as intended when installed from apt, failed to open the files I wanted due to snap's filesystem sandboxing, citing a lack of permission. It's one of the main reasons I hate snaps but sadly it seems like Ubuntu is moving towards them more and more.

Is there a way to give snaps access to the entire filesystem? Or at least **everything** under my home directory? Preferably in a way that it is also applied for any snaps I install in the future. I couldn't find anything by searching around the internet. And no, don't tell me it's a bad idea for security, I would've installed the snaps I have as native installs with exactly this kind of permission long ago, if the non-snap versions in the Ubuntu repos were up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *devmode* (developer mode)flag when you are installing snap packages. You can activate it when installing a snap package from the Snap Store, and it runs unconfined.

Suppose you want to install `inkscape` as *--devmode*. First, uninstall it, then install with the `--devmode` flag.

```
sudo snap remove inkscape
sudo snap install inkscape --devmode
```

To verify, run the following. Note the *devmode* at the end of the line.

```
$ snap info inkscape
...
installed:          1.0rc1             (7485) 150MB devmode
$
```

While the application will be able to read from anywhere on the filesystem, the `/tmp/` is still private to the application (it is `/tmp/snap.inkscape/`).