# How to TOTALLY disable snap sandboxing, including /tmp?

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04

I want to run a snap application without ANY sandboxing, which means it can directly access ALL files in the filesystem (if the user has the right to access them), including the user's home directory, or even the `/tmp` directory.

The current case is that I want to install Kubuntu 22.04, in which Firefox is installed via snap. I usually use `/tmp` to download things that I don't want to stay in my filesystem forever. However, as snap sandboxes the `/tmp` directory, even in `--devmode`, it's impossible to do so from now on.

Similar question: [How to disable snap filesystem sandboxing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227963/how-to-disable-snap-filesystem-sandboxing#1228061), but it doesn't solve the `/tmp` case.

Note: It seems like it is still April 22, 2022 in my timezone, but Ubuntu's website is now recommending downloading the 22.04 ISO, so I assume that 22.04 is now released.

Answer (score -2):

To run a snap without strict confinement, you will want to use the `--classic` flag when (re)installing:

```
sudo snap install firefox --classic
```

You can [read more about Snap confinement here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)

Comment: Thank you! Let me test it after upgrading my Ubuntu! I will give up/down votes after that.

Comment: This does not work. `Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap firefox`.

Comment: Indeed, whether you are "allowed" to install a snaps in "classic" mode is determined by the snap packager: for many snaps, you can not do it (objectionary, such "proprietary" control, but here we are...)